# When I use rotation matrix z- position doesn't move. why?

Tags: rotations, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to rotate 3 points around x- axis.

and three points are (1.33, 2.49, 0),(2.5, 4.33, 0),(0, 5, 0). which is on the xy plane

rotation angle is pi/4. then, I followed this cacultation.

[image]

but I think z position should not be zero and x position should be fixed as it rotated around x-axis, right?
but the result is different. Could you give me any comment about this? Is there anything I missing now?

Comment: Can you clarify you notation? I don't know if embedded brackets (i.e., [[]]) mean a row or a column vector. If it means a row vector such that $[1.33,2.49,0]$ is the first row, then you need to transpose it to make it a column for your method to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do three points at once?  That's not how matrix multiplication works.  You appear to have a rotation matrix given by

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\sqrt2&-\sqrt2\\0&\sqrt2&\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$$
and you want to use that to rotate your point.  So do your matrix multiplication on the first point:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\sqrt2&-\sqrt2\\0&\sqrt2&\sqrt2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1.33\\2.49\\0\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}1\times1.33+0\times2.49+0\times2.49\\
0\times1.33+\sqrt2\times2.49-\sqrt2\times0\\
0\times1.33+\sqrt2\times2.49+\sqrt2\times0\end{bmatrix}$$
by taking each member of a row times each member of a column and adding.  Then you can do the same for the other points.

EDIT based on comment below: And if you do want to do them all at once, you need to put each point as a *column* in your right-hand matrix, not a row.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about doing multiple positions at once. For a $3\times 3$ rotation matrix $\mathbf{T}$ and $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times N}$, where each column is a position vector, the columns of the product $\mathbf{TB}$ will be the correct rotated positions.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Oh, I see how the OP's notation was supposed to work.  I was somehow thinking he was trying to do this line by line (one line of rotation matrix with one point).  I'll edit appropriately, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to rotate three points at once; however, the matrix of vectors that you have constructed is incorrect, instead of your current matrix:

$$\mathbf{x}^{T}=\begin{pmatrix}1.33 & 2.49 & 0 \\ 2.5 & 4.33 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

You need:

$$\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}1.33 & 2.5 & 0 \\ 2.49 & 4.33 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

If you then multiply by your rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}(\frac{\pi}{4})=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{2} & -\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2}\end{smallmatrix}\right)$:

$$\mathbf{x}'=\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}1.33 & 2.5 & 0 \\ 3.52 & 6.12 & 7.07 \\ 3.52 & 6.12 & 7.07\end{pmatrix}$$

In general if you have vectors $\vec{v}_{1},\dots,\vec{v}_{m}\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$, in order to rotate them using a linear map $\mathbf{M}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ you need to construct the matrix:

$$\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}\uparrow & & \uparrow \\ \vec{v}_{1} & \cdots & \vec{v}_{m} \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow\end{pmatrix}$$

And then compute the product $\mathbf{M}\mathbf{x}$ to get your matrix where the columns are your transformed vectors.